# MySQL why logged as slow query/log-queries-not-using-indexes when have indexes?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, indexing, myisam

Mysql 5.1.x

in my.cnf:

```
log-queries-not-using-indexes = 1
long_query_time = 30
and slow queries are logged
```

Why I show this at log? Not slow and all fields are indexed.

From mysql.slow.log:

```
# Query_time: 0.001492  Lock_time: 0.000031 Rows_sent: 229  Rows_examined: 458
use database1;
SET timestamp=1393342939;
SELECT id,name FROM database1 ORDER BY name ASC;
```

This table has 229 rows, MYISAM.

```
id and name are indexed
id = auto increment int unsigned
name = varchar(255) utf-8
```

Can you explain why I show this at not indexed/slow query log?

**Summary and more information:**

MYISAM TABLE, 229 rows, more columns but all, 229 needed with id and name column. Both has index. At query need all 229 rows to show.

I want 2 things:

- 1.: **Don't show that query at slow query/not-using-indexes log.**
- 2.: **Make that query fast as possible.**

Thanks.

Comment: "why I show this at not indexed/slow query log" --- slow query log isn't about queries that don't use indexes, but about queries that are executing slowly. PS: for the given query and dataset size I don't see any index that can be useful.

Comment: Query time is 3000x less than in configuration. This is strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing a literal full scan of the table, since you've got no WHERE predicates to index by.

Comment: If I add to this query: SELECT id,name FROM database1 WHERE id>0 ORDER BY name ASC; // will ok and not in this log? I will try it... What is the best way to get all data from table and be a fastest? Like I get 10 from 10 county name from database, for example...

Comment: No! the general idea of an index is to be able to find a subset of a table faster without having to evaluate every row for the amount of given conditions. id>0 assuming id is always positive will also give you a full scan (Because you are conceptually pulling every record from the table). There is no optimization you can do in such a query and i doubt you can get less than 1.5ms out of that execute.

Comment: An index would be meaningful if for example you had 100 rows in that table and you wanted to bring the one with id=1. At that point you'd need to create and index on the id field and your EXPLAIN PLAN would reflect the usage of an index.

Comment: a) That query, with that table will never use an index. Even hinting the query to use one will for sure be counter productive.

Comment: b) Regarding what is logged, take a look at this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/slow-query-log.html, check the settings for : --log-queries-not-using-indexes,

Comment: Can be a stupid question, but if I add more rows, started with 1000 and I select WHERE id<1000 and select 229 rows, will faster when now use indexes than before? :-)

Comment: No, it will actually be slower, if you did manage to accomplish what you are trying to accomplish. "full scans are not evil, indexes are not good". https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9422487749968