# Mysql: Why are these queries being 'logged' as 'not using indexes' when they

Tags: mysql, logging, indexing

So, I'm trying to find joins that aren't properly using indexes, but the log is being filled with queries which appear to have indexes to me.

I turn on slow_query_log and turn on log_queries_not_using_indexes    and set the long_query_time to 10 seconds.

The log starts flooding with lines like this...

```
Query_time: 0.320889  Lock_time: 0.000030 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 338336
SET timestamp=1422564398;
select * from fversions where author=155669 order by entryID desc limit 40;
```

The query time is below 10 seconds, and from this explain, it seems to be using the primary key as the index.

Why is this query being logged? I can't see the problem queries to add indexes to them. Too much noise.

Thanks in advance!

PS. The answer for this doesn't seem to apply as I have a 'where'. [MySQL why logged as slow query/log-queries-not-using-indexes when have indexes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22024148/mysql-why-logged-as-slow-query-log-queries-not-using-indexes-when-have-indexes)

```
mysql> explain select * from fversions where author=155669 order by entryID desc limit 40;
+----+-------------+-----------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table     | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-----------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------
|  1 | SIMPLE      | fversions | index | NULL          | PRIMARY | 8       | NULL |   40 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-----------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+----
```

> Blockquote

--+------
    1 row in set (0.00 sec)

```
mysql> show variables like 'slow_query_log';
+----------------+-------+
| Variable_name  | Value |
+----------------+-------+
| slow_query_log | ON    |

mysql> show variables like 'long_query_time';
+-----------------+-----------+
| Variable_name   | Value     |
+-----------------+-----------+
| long_query_time | 10.000000 |

mysql> show variables like 'log_queries_not_using_indexes';
+-------------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name                 | Value |
+-------------------------------+-------+
| log_queries_not_using_indexes | ON    |
```